# bash for loop is ending early when I add a an array populated grep results, and I can't figure out why

Tags: bash, for-loop

Can't seem to figure out why my for loop is exiting early. It seems to crash when running the grep command that feeds the array.

set -x is not giving me any insight here. When i replace the `nb_search_results=($(grep $search_string $i/.index)` line with simply `echo $I` it continues through the loop as expected. Any idea why? Is grep loop kryptonite?

```sh
nb_search_titles() {
  local search_string=$1

  for i in "$NB_PATH"/* ; do
    nb_search_results=($(grep $search_string $i/.index))
    if ! [[ -z ${nb_search_results[@]} ]] ; then
      printf "%s:\n%s\n" "${i##*/}" "${nb_search_results[@]}"
    fi
  done
}
```

Comment: Did you use `set -e` or `set -o errexit` or run it with `bash -e` or something like that?

Comment: Please include some real life input/output, otherwise we can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: Try addressing the issues brought up by shellcheck.net. For example,  make sure you [quote variable references](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: BTW, that `printf` is going to behave weirdly if there's more than one match (or more than one word in the matched line(s)).

Comment: My guess: grep is segfaulting. Check if you have a recent core dump in the script directory. If it is the case, debug it or provide a link for it. @GordonDavisson is right, if there is multiple `$search_string`  on the same line in some of your .index file you'll get : `file:\n$search_string\n$search_string:\n$search_string etc.`.